Mass Editing Hyperlinks in Excel
I am making a Contact Excel Sheet I am using for work and I am storing peoples LinkedIn Profiles in this document.
I am trying to keep the displayed size of the the links down so I am at presetn entering links via the Hyperlink Function and then changing the text displayed as 'Profile'
This is tedious, is there a formula or VBA to basically take a hyperlink in column K and change the display to 'Profile'?
I am using Excel 2013.

Do you mean you're using the Hyperlink formula:  =HYPERLINK("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79226205/mass-editing-hyperlinks-in-excel","Mass Editing Hyperlinks in Excel"), or the hyperlink is in the cell and you're right-clicking, selecting Edit Hyperlink and manually updating the Text to Display part of the dialog box?

This will update the Text To Display in each hyperlink on Sheet1.
Public Sub UpdateTextToDisplay()

    Dim HL As Hyperlink
    
    For Each HL In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Hyperlinks
        HL.TextToDisplay = "Profile"
    Next HL

End Sub  

Use this code to update the hyperlinks in a single column (I think you can use Columns("K") instead of Columns(11) if you prefer):
Public Sub UpdateTextToDisplay()

    Dim HL As Hyperlink
    
    For Each HL In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(11).Hyperlinks
        HL.TextToDisplay = "Profile"
    Next HL

End Sub



Hi Darren, is there a way this can be edited to only handle 1 Column (K)? I ask as I also have email addresses on this sheet which I assume will be treated as hyperlinks?

Have edited to use a single column.

Worked Perfectly! Thank you!
